# how to modify this code to stretch the image to full screen in android

Tags: android, image, scale, drawable

I got some code it draws images according to the size of the image. but i want to stretch the image to full screen. i tried a lot but nothing really helped.  Can any do this for me? thanks in advance

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        b.eraseColor(0xF000FFFF);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);

        int margin = 1;
        int border =1 ;
        Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

        int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
        int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
            imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
            imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                    / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }

        r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
        r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
        r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
        r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

        Paint p = new Paint(); 
        p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
        c.drawRect(r, p);
        r.left += border;
        r.right -= border;
        r.top += border;
        r.bottom -= border;

        d.setBounds(r);
        d.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: try setting as background image rather as src image it will stretch but can deform the image

Answer (score 0):

check out this.................onClick method of your thumbnail, you can start a new Activity in fullscreen mode:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and pass the image uri or something which indicate the image source to the new activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YouActivity.this, FullImage.class);  
intent.putExtra("imageUri", R.drawable.yourImage); // or the path to your image.
```

in FullImage Activity class

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);  
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inTempStorage = new byte[3*1024];  
Bitmap ops = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); // instead path you can get an image from previous activity.   
icon.setImageBitmap(ops);
```